# How to convert this line from PHP into Ruby?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have trouble with converting the following line from PHP to Ruby:

```
strtolower(preg_replace(array('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/', '/[ -]+/', '/^-|-$/'), array('', '-', ''), trim($str)));
```

Is it possible to accomplish this in one line just like in here?

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that on one line? Do you not care about ever working with this code in future or someone else having to work with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str.strip.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/, '').gsub(/[ -]+/, '-').gsub(/^-|-$/, '').downcase
```

could be further simplified to:

```
str.strip.gsub(/[ -]+/, '-').gsub(/[^a-z \d-]|^-|-$/i, '').downcase
```